# Buy Now Button/IPN Simulator

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have set up a Buy Now button on my website.
Upon transaction being completed I then direct the PayPal data to a script on my server. 
What I need to know is, is the data sent by the Buy Now button the same as that sent when using the IPN Simulator?
If not, where do I find a list of the variables/data sent by the Buy Now button?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IPN simulator Web Accept Transaction Type should simulate the same information back to your IPN listener.

This is the documentation link for all the IPN variable that PayPal will returned to your listener. 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/